# Merging branch to develop huge conflicts

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, version

My repository has the following two main branches: `master` and `beta` - a while ago I branched off `beta` to doo some work in isolation. A lot of work. The idea was to keep it separate from the other team member so that they can continue. In that time they made commits to `beta`

Fast forward to today; and now I want to `merge` my changes back into `beta` - using Git Tower I checked out `feature` - pulled `beta` into `feature` - fixed the merge conflicts and committed the changes to my repo on the origin `feature` branch - when doing a PR into `beta` I am still hit with merge conflicts.

So I tried to pull `beta` into `feature` again locally and the exact same conflicts happen.

At this point I am at a loss. How can I get my changes into `beta` ?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say what happened without seeing the state before and after the merge.
It could be that you didn't push to the right feature branch or maybe you did a rebase... we would need the exact steps you are performing and we need to ensure that you successfully completed the merge and pushed those changes.

If you merge your `beta` branch again into your `feature` branch, does it also show merge conflicts? If not, then your PR is not correctly updated, most likely because you didn‘t really push the changes.

Or perhaps a very simple explanation: Your PR is not based on the `beta` branch as you thought but on another.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to resolve this using a rebase from `beta` branch